# Xamarin, Open RDP connection into ContentView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, remote-desktop

I'm checking to undertand if there are a way to open RDP session 
   into my xamarin application.
   Using the "intent" the rdp connection work and open the session into a new task, but my goal is to open the RDP into a particular content view.

But I cannot retrive that information.

Thank you
Alberto